# Ajax POST (CORS Enabled) Always Erroring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I have the following function to perform an ajax post request

```
function POST(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        'type' : "POST",
        'url' : url,
        'data' : data,
        headers : {
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' : '*'
        },
        success : function(msg) {
            //alert('in success');
            //alert(msg);
            return msg;
        },
        error : function (xhr, status, error) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            return 'error';
        }
    });
}
```

The function is always returning with an error dues to my CORS configuration.

The error I get is always

> {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

I tried the same request in Google Chrome with the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension enabled and the request goes through fine, so I am fairly confident it is entirely an issue with my code not configuring CORS properly.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is the server you are POSTing to CORS-enabled? Is it handling the pre-flight request properly?

Comment: I believe so, but it works with the mentioned Chrome extension enabled so it must be.

Comment: @yitzih Shouldn't the http method be like below `method: "POST"`

Comment: I had a problem with this, because the request was JSONP. Maybe this could be the problem.

Comment: @GabrielMesquita you cannot use jsonp with POST ... I can see this ajax call is using POST here.

Comment: @Niladri I see, in my case it wase a GET request.

Comment: usually the problem are on the server not on clien-side, please check your server

Comment: _"but it works with the mentioned Chrome extension enabled so it must be"_ - that's the opposite of the right conclusion ... this extension _circumvents_ CORS restrictions, it is a tool to enable such requests in situations where the server did not allow it. So your successful request with this extension enabled pretty much proofs that your server is _not_ enabling it properly.

Comment: What is your dev console telling you?

Comment: Remove the `headers : {
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' : '*'
        }` from your code. The `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header isn’t something you can control from your code; instead it’s strictly just something the browser uses when the browser automatically on its own sends a CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below method

```
function POST(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : data,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            //xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            //xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
         xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","x-requested-with");
        },
        success : function(msg) {
            //alert('in success');
            //alert(msg);
            return msg;
        },
        error : function (xhr, status, error) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            return 'error';
        }
    });
}
```

if you are using jquery 1.5.2+ then you need to add the below header

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with`

Comment: I added in the `crossDomain : true` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-requested-with'` but still have the same issue. Is `x-requested-with` a placeholder or the actual text for the content of that header? (I am using JQuery 3.2.1)

Comment: @yitzih updated my answer. You can also use `beforeSend` to set headers as key value pairs. Notice the missing single quote in my answer

Comment: @yitzih can you print the `status, error` of the error handler in ajax call in console.log . Also which datatype are you sending in the `data` attribute. Does the server accepts that datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the CORS are accepting all sources in the back-end ?

Bye :)